# how to detect keypress and keyrelease of keys like "shift","Enter","Capslock" in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

this works for normal keys like [q,w,e,r,1,2,3] but i cant make it work with keys like with Shift,Enter,Backspace etc,any idea how to make it work?

```py
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
def func1(event):
    print(f'{event.char} key was pressed')
def func2(event):
    print(f'{event.char} key was released')
root.bind("<KeyPress>",func1)
root.bind("<KeyPress>",func2)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Normally Modifier Keys will be detected [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72917102/13629335) why would you bind Capslock. Just to be noisy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

> `.char`:
> If the event was related to a KeyPress or KeyRelease for a key that produces a regular ASCII character, this string will be set to that character. (For special keys like delete, see the .keysym attribute, below.)

Since here you are trying to get a special key like Shift, Caps and so on, you can use `keysym` which will provide the key name.

Based on your comments, I see that you were expecting for a function that will trigger when the Shift key was pressed and released. This can be achieved by using `KeyPress` and `KeyRelease` before the key name:

```
def func1(event):
    print(f'{event.keysym} key was pressed')
def func2(event):
    print(f'{event.keysym} key was released')

root.bind("<KeyPress-Shift_L>",func1)
root.bind("<KeyRelease-Shift_L>",func2)
```

Some useful reference links:

- [54.6. Writing your handler: The Event class](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/event-handlers.html)
- [54.5. Key names](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/key-names.html)

Answer (score 1):

you have to use these to .bind function :

```
root.bind("<Alt-s>",fAlt) # Alt+s pressed
root.bind("<Control-c>",func) # C character + Ctrl
root.bind("<Alt>",func1)  # The Alt key is held
root.bind("<Control>",func2)  # The Ctrl key is held
root.bind("<Shift>",func3)  # The Shift key is held
root.bind("<KeyPress>",func4)

root.bind('<Left>', leftKey)
root.bind('<Right>', rightKey)
root.bind('<Up>', upKey)
root.bind('<Down>', downKey)
```

Comment: i want it to be so that when shift is pressed a function will be executed and as soon as it is released another will be executed so just binding doesnt work,or is there a way to make it work by just binding shift?

Comment: you can use function GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) in win32api for python

Comment: does it work in ubuntu?

Comment: no , It is for windows,

Comment: ahhhh i m on ubuntu rn