# Why i can't use tkinter to bind parenleft or parenright?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, keyboard-events

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.title('test')
        self.geometry('300x500')
        self.bind('<parenleft>', lambda event: self.show())
        self.bind('<parenright>', lambda event: self.show())

    def show(self):
        print('get')


def main():
    app = Application()
    app.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I‘ve also tryed like `self.bind('<Key-parenleft>')` and `self.bind('<Shift-9>')`, they aslo didn't work.

I've checked in the [this website](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/keysyms.html) and i am sure the name of the key is correct, but it doesn't work,it's really stchange.

I want to know how to fix the problem and what cause th problem, thank you.

Comment: Read the documentation carefully *Tk recognizes many keysyms when specifying key bindings (e.g., “bind . <**Key-**keysym>”)*

Comment: @Thingamabobs Sorry,I don't understand what do you meean,could say moe clearly, Thank you

Comment: `self.bind('<Key-parenleft>',...` should work.

Comment: @Thingamabobs It's still not work...

Comment: What does not work? You need to clarify the desired behavior and the concrete issue you are facing.

Comment: I mean that the programm can't detect that i pushed `Shift-9` just the `(`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247622/discussion-between-danhui-xu-and-thingamabobs).

Comment: @Thingamabobs: `<parentleft>` is correct, it doesn't keey `Key-` before it.

Comment: This code works fine for me. When I press `(` or `)` I get the output in the console.

Comment: @BryanOakley thanks for making me aware of it. But I'm curious since I always wrote '<KeyPress-W>' . But by thinking of it I never did it with *Return* . Now that OP shows the sign of `(` I actually understand what is meant with the keysym *parenleft*. Modifier Keys  are in [event.state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72917102/13629335) and due the signal modification the registered sequence is never toggled.

Comment: @BryanOakley must be a [Windows](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/KeySyms+on+platforms+other+than+X11) user like me.

Comment: No, I use a Macintosh.