# tkinter event binding not handled correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a function in a tkinter application that does some operations on the content of the clipboard, pastes the result to a Text widget, and then should return to the previous application. For the last part I'm generating an Alt-Tab using pynput.

```
def invert_clipboard(e=None):
    txt = root.clipboard_get()
    if not txt:
        return
    tokens = re.split('\s+', txt.strip())
    if len(tokens) >= 2:
        out = tokens[len(tokens)-1].strip() + ', ' 
        for i in range(len(tokens)-1):
            out += tokens[i]
            if i < len(tokens) - 2:
                out += ' '
    else:
        out = txt.strip()
    out += '#'
    input_text.insert(tk.INSERT, out)
    global dirty
    dirty = True
    thread = Thread(target=switch_window)
    thread.start()

def switch_window():
    root.update_idletasks()
    with keyboard.pressed(Key.alt):
        keyboard.press(Key.tab)
        keyboard.release(Key.tab)
        keyboard.release(Key.alt)
```

The function can be accessed via a menu item:

```
macros_menu.add_command(
        label='Invert',
        command=invert_clipboard,
        accelerator="Ctrl+M"
```

or via a keyboard shortcut:

```
root.bind('<Control-m>', lambda event:invert_clipboard(None))
```

When called from the menu, everything works as intended; when called from the keyboard shortcut, the return to previous doesn't quite work. I see the group of thumbnails of the open apps, with the expected app highlighted, but pressing Enter is required to maximize it.

I assume I'm not handling the keyboard event correctly in the bind, but I have only a murky understanding of how to do so. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify, your command gets executed but has a different outcome when you use the binding?

Comment: The command is executed, but when invoked via the keyboard accelerator it does not return successfully to the previous application (Acrobat in this case, but it could be anything).

Comment: This doesn't seems to be related to the binding then. The job of the binding is just to invoke a method on certain event sequence. Could you extend your snippet with the code how you implement *the return to previous doesn't quite work* part?

Comment: That is implemented by the four keyboard.press / keyboard.release statements in the example. This technique works if I invoke via the menu command, but not if I invoke via the keyboard.

Comment: Sorry didn't pay attention at the time. I would have 3 suggestions with try and error. 1) `root.update_idletasks()`  before your Key invocation. 2) Put the key invocation into another function that you call via `root.after(20, lambda: switch_window())`. 3) Put *switch_window* in a different thread.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately, none of them changed the behavior. I've updated my original question with the complete and updated functions.

Comment: I nearly forgot about you. Please use the @User to send them a notification about your reply. You could try another one, but first forget about the thread thing since it has no effect. Try `root.event_generate('<FocusOut>')` then use `root.update_idletasks()` before you invoke your keys.

Comment: Just checked it, has not the intended effect. Use `root.lower()` instead of event_generate

Comment: Hi @Thingamabobs Thanks for your continued interest. Using `root.lower()` kind of works, so that's progress :-) The current app gets minimized, but the actual focus is still on the screen of app thumbnails rather than the previous app. In a two-screen environment, it almost looks like success!

Comment: Minimized? That's odd, it should get lower (probably lowest) in the z-order of your currently open windows. Do you have any attributes set like *-topmost*, *overrideredirect* or *grab_set*. Can you show  basically the configuration of your window?

Comment: Let's try another one: use `root.wm_attributes('-disabled', True)` and reverse it after you done. If that and any combination of these commands don't help, I would need to consider installing that package. ^^

Comment: @Thingamabobs I guess you're right, the app was not minimized, just out of sight. Moving onward, bad and good news. Using `root.wm_attributes` didn't help, but adding a `keyboard.press(Key.enter)` to the end of the key sequence seems to work (cleanly switches to the previous app, no app thumbnails shown), but inconsistently, like about 50% of the time. When it doesn't work, my main screen shows the app thumbnails, and the secondary screen (the one I'm working in) shows the app that was switched to, which has focus. So the goal would be to not see the app thumbnails.

Comment: What system do you work with?

Comment: @Thingamabobs Windows 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem that you are facing is that you have an additional and unwanted [modifier key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72917102/13629335) pressed during the event and that changes the behavior. You can check this by just trying the key combination `CTRL+ALT+TAB` without running any script. You could solve it by changing your `bind` in a manner that it works without `CTRL` or you release that key before you invoke your desired key combination.

```
import tkinter as tk
import ctypes

ALT = 0x12
TAB = 0x09
SHIFT = 0x10
CTRL = 0x11
PRESS = 0x0000
RELEASE = 0x0002

keyevent = ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event

def show_next(event=None):
    keyevent(CTRL,0,RELEASE,0)
    keyevent(ALT,0,PRESS,0)
    keyevent(TAB,0,PRESS,0)
    keyevent(TAB,0,RELEASE,0)
    keyevent(ALT,0,RELEASE,0)
    

def show_prev(event=None):
    keyevent(CTRL,0,RELEASE,0)
    keyevent(ALT,0,PRESS,0)
    keyevent(SHIFT,0,PRESS,0)
    keyevent(TAB,0,PRESS,0)
    keyevent(TAB,0,RELEASE,0)
    keyevent(SHIFT,0,RELEASE,0)
    keyevent(ALT,0,RELEASE,0)

root = tk.Tk()
btn1 = tk.Button(root, text='Next', command= show_next)
btn1.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
btn2 = tk.Button(root, text='Prev', command= show_prev)
btn2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
root.bind('<Control-n>', show_next)
root.bind('<Control-p>', show_prev)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Thingmabobs Well, your example certainly works, and doesn't work (that is, works as well as before) when I incorporate it in to my app. BUT: it inadvertently gave me a clue. All this fussing may have been a bunch of red herrings. The problem seems to be the choice of hot key. If I change mine to 'n' as in your example, it works perfectly. If I change your example to use my hot key, it stops working. I did some testing, and so far the only thing I have come up with is that composite hotkeys such as Ctrl-M, Shift-F1 are bad, and simple hotkeys like F1 and 'n' are good. What do you think?

Comment: @RodneyBoyd Thanks for your feedback. I have updated the answer, did not know about this key combination before. Seems we learned both from your question. Besides I would ask you to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/828183) this answer, since it should solve your issue.